# How to configure SMPPsim to support multiple clients

Tags: java

I am doing some test and scenario would be SMPPsim should listen to two clients, I have 2 engines and need to bind them to single `SMPPsim` . however when I initiate send_SMS, only 1 engine binds to my SMPPsim.

config: netstat -tulpan | grep java
0.0.0.0 2775 listen  2079/java >> means port 2775 is the listen port. 
x.x.x.x 2775 established 2079/java >> smppsim binds to this IP only. other clients doesn't appear.

Is there a config needed to bind to multiple clients.
hoping for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In *conf/smppsim.pros* of SMPPsim, there exists two parameters (`SYSTEM_IDS` and `PASSWORDS`) to define credentials of possible clients. I give my configuration below:

```
SYSTEM_IDS=smsc1,smsc2
PASSWORDS=password,password
```

(Possible credentials: smsc1:password, smsc2:password)

So, you can connect more than one instances of your client to a single instance of SMPPsim. But, each client must establish the connection with a different SYSTEM_ID-PASSWORD pair.

Another way is creating distinct instances of SMPPsim each of which listens to a different port. You can therefore connect your clients to different SMPPsim processes. If this is appropriate for you, don't forget change `SMPP_PORT` parameter (in *conf/smppsim.pros*) for each instance. Otherwise, you will get a "port is already in use" error.

Comment: actually, I already tested this setup, my Engine1 used smppclient1/password, and my engine2 is using smppclient2/password. based on logs, bind request was succesfull. but if I queried java instance on 1 IPadd/port was established.

Comment: tcp 0  0 0.0.0.0:10000  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      3942/java           
tcp 0  0 0.0.0.0:2775   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      3942/java           
tcp 0  0 192.168.20.39:2775 192.168.20.39:54630 ESTABLISHED 3942/java

Comment: is there any version requirements that can support multiple peering.